# Не переходит в папку при помощи командной строки

Tags: cmd, командная-строка

> C:>cd\Projects
>
> C:\Projecjs>cd\SomeProject
> Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Не могу перейти в папку. Как исправить ?

Comment: У вас опечатка в имени папки? Также, не нужен слэш. Должно быть просто `cd имя_папки` (т.е. через пробел)

Comment: Не писать обратный слэш там где он не нужен

Comment: Покажи нам путь.